# Oracle FK constraint reverse engineering using SQL Developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

I got homework to analyze how FK constraints work and simulate it using Java/JDBC.

Is it possible to figure out that a DBMS is processing foreign keys in sequence using
only SQL Developer and INSERT statement?

```
INSERT INTO GRADES (idn, idu, idp, ido, kind) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 'C')
```

(idn, idu, idp, and ido are FKs.)

I did test all combinations of valid/invalid keys--I noticed that the DBMS gives only one exception at a time (even if a few FKs are invalid) and it checks them from right to left--I will get an exception only for ido in case ido is invalid, validity of the rest is irrelevant, or I will get an exception for idp if ido is valid and idn and idu might be valid or invalid.

Can I infer that the algorithm in the above case looks like this?

```
    if(!isValid(ido) {
        throw new SQLexception(ido);
    } else if(!isValid(idp) {
        throw new SQLexception(idp);
    } else if(!isValid(idu) {
        throw new SQLexception(idu);
    } else if(!isValid(idn) {
        throw new SQLexception(idn);
    }
```

What is a better way to check how a DBMS is verifying FK constraints?

Comment: Are you sure that you have understood the question? I don't think there is a documented deterministic order for checking foreign keys. It would surprise me as that would limit performance improvements for no clear benefit. Perhaps they rather wanted you to experiment with different scenarios to see how it works? Do they bite at commit or immediately, for example?

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. All defined contraints will be checked but you cannot controle the specific ordering. But above all, why do you care? All constraints need to be correct or the data won't be inserted.

Comment: @ewramner I am pretty sure that this is about 'in sequence or not in sequence'; I did one class giving perfect exceptions but it was checking all tables with PK at once  (single SELECT) - the teacher said that messages were good but it was not FK constraints emulation; I am bit frustrated, because i can test oracle as a black box only, while the teacher is testing my class as a white box; if he would test it as a black box, he could not tell the difference.

Comment: If you have to analyse how FK constraints work, why are you looking at a proprietary database that is closed-source? Instead, look at an open-source database and then you can read the source code and figure out exactly how it works and what order that database applies the constraints.

Comment: What is your 1 clear specific researched non-duplicate question? "is it possible to figure out that DBMS is processing FKs in sequence using only SQL Developer and INSERT statement?" You cannot tell anything about a program by observing its output except that it output what you saw when you saw it. There is never any way to "check" by observation. Was this an assignment? What exactly did it say? Why are you asking this? PS Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please give a [mre] in code questions. [ask] [Help] If you want to know what the program will do, read the relevant manuals.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] PS Looking at a different program than a given program tells you nothing about the given program.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to figure out that DBMS is processing FKs in sequence using only SQL Developer and INSERT statement?

No (if you **ONLY** have SQL Developer and an `INSERT` statement).

---

SQL Developer is a client application (an IDE) that is run locally by the user to talk to a database (that may be remote or local). Other than performing syntax highlighting and checking, SQL Developer effectively does no processing of SQL statements. The client application will send those SQL statements to the database for the database's SQL engine to evaluate and then will wait for the database to respond and display the response to user. It is the database that will parse the SQL statements.

If you only have SQL Developer then you do **NOT** have a database and there is nothing to process the SQL statements and there will be no tables to insert into and there will be no foreign key constraints. You have to have a database.

Comment: @all SQL Developer is a tool that enables me to communicate with my Oracle instance. The inquiry pertains to utilizing SQL Developer as an investigative instrument for uncovering the methods through which the DBMS enforces foreign key integrity mechanisms. Is it possible at all? I doubt so, but I'd like to have 2nd opinion :]

Comment: @Damian Your question specifically asks about "using only SQL Developer and INSERT statement". By specifying **only** that software, it specifically excludes a database instance and the answer is "No". If you expand the question to include SQL Developer and an Oracle instance then: (a) SQL Developer is irrelevant as you could replace it with any other client application; and (b) you are asking how the internals work of closed-source proprietary software and for that you need to ask Oracle (who won't tell you). Alternatively, you can look at the source-code of any other open-source RDBMS.

Comment: if row_ins_check_foreign_constraints is a function i am looking for, it means that it stops checking FKs on a 1st invalid key (mysql 5.5.62)

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to figure out that DBMS is processing FKs in sequence using only SQL Developer and INSERT statement?

No. Sequence of foreign key evaluation is not guarantied, so even if you'll find out sequence based on some kind of suit test, sequence may change with update, change of load of load on server, change of optimization, if you're in maintenance window, etc.

You cannot fully simulate DBMS behavior since it is not possible to simulate even using DBMS itself.

The best you can do within setup of "only INSERT" is to INSERT and ROLLBACK.
And see what error was raised if any.

Second best strategy select sequence of foreign key checks you like and use it. Information on **what** foreign key is violated is not important: what is important is a fact that one or more of them **were violated**.